# Alternative to trains in Japan

Tags: budget, public-transport, japan

So we all know about these pretty amazing trains they have in the "Land of the Rising Sun". They are always on time, clean, comfortable. But they are somewhat expensive for the average backpacker.

I'm aware of the Japan Rail Pass and I'm really considering buying it for my upcoming trip there but I'm still evaluating alternatives.

What about buses? Would it be possible to sacrifice some comfort in order to save money and move around Japan (Honshu and Kyushu mostly) with flexibility? Is there something like JRP for buses (it would be cool if you could use it even for buses inside cities)?

Comment: Bullet trains (Shinkansen) are expensive but there are also slower trains and their prices can be considerably lower. Not as low as buses though, and even buses can vary in price in Japan though all the buses I rode on or saw were very modern and comfortable.

Comment: get the Japan Rail pass. One Shinkansen trip makes it worthwhile.

Comment: I've done both routes (JRP and buses). Sleeping (or more like, not-sleeping) on an overnight bus from Tokyo to Kyoto was not worth it, especially when looking back we traveled around enough that it would have cheaper to buy the JRP and have access to the shinkansen than buy individual bus tickets and limited subway passes for Tokyo, etc.

Comment: Pretty much none, overnight buses suck just like they do everywhere in the world (plus they aren't much cheaper). Try taking the regular zairai-sen trains, perhaps with some transfers, and visit some places along the way. Also try the JR pass; you can now buy it in major JR stations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Seishun 18 ticket is great, but for any lengthy journeys (Tokyo -> Kyoto, for example), it's a bit of a pain requiring lots of changes and takes longer than the bus. However, used well it is *extremely* cheap.

As an alternative [Willer Express](http://willerexpress.com/en/), a budget highway bus company, offers the [Japan Bus Pass](http://willerexpress.com/st/3/en/pc/buspass/index.php). It allows 3, 4 or 5 days travel within 2 months for 10, 12 or 14,000 yen respectively. The pass can be used for daytime or overnight travel. On each 'day' of the pass you can either take:

- 1 or 2 daytime bus(es)
- 1 overnight bus
- 1 daytime + 1 overnight bus

The days can be used at any point during the 2 months, allowing you to stop over or use other forms of transport along the way. Of course this is only good for routes that Willer Express serves, however that covers most of the urban centres in Japan.

Note: the bus pass must be purchased outside of Japan, but is usable by tourists and residents alike.

Answer (score 15):

An (often cheaper) alternative to trains are [highway buses](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2366.html) - especially when you use overnight routes that save you one night of accomodation. I'm not aware of any JRP-like flatrate tickets though.

Another very interesting option is the [Seishun 18](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/seishun18.html) ticket, which allows 5 (unconnected) days of unlimited JR train use for 11,500 yen - but only using local/regional trains, so for long-distance travel you have to change trains a lot and take much longer than with the Shinkansen (up to 4 times as long on some routes). Unfortuantely, it is only available/valid during holiday seasons.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative, are domestic flights; however, these can be as pricey as some of the Shinkansen train rides, but they are quicker.

But to see the scenery, the Highway Bus, as mentioned is the way to go.  I lived in Japan for 4 years and travelled quite extensively across the country, using all 3 main modes of transport - I don't have a favourite per se, but I have to say that the Highway bus journey was comfortable, albeit a little cramped (for me being 6'5), and very enjoyable - a very pleasant way to see the countryside roll by.

Comment: 6'5 = 195 cm... big guy ;)

Comment: To provide some perspective, Japan and Korea are getting a lot more tall young people in the last generation or two compared to all other East and Southeast Asian countries. You can't expect as much space as in Northern Europe but more space than in many developing countries. For instance I'm 6'1" / 185cm and I'm always comfortable in Korea but can't fit my legs into spaces provided in Vietnam.

Answer (score 1):

When I was last in Tokyo (Ocotober 2012) they were advertising a tourists day pass for Tokyo. I think it allowed for unlimited train travel for the day for 1,000 yen. Might only have been in and around Tokyo though.

Comment: Could you perhaps look it up and see if you can find the details? A link with concrete information would be great for the OP.

Comment: I'll see if I can find the ticket. I was there for work so I think think I had to submit the receipt for expenses.
I don't speak much Japanese so I'm not sure where to start. TBH: I'd get a Japan Rail Pass if I ever go to Japan again, the value is amazing.

Comment: maybe you mean the Tokunai Pass (都区内パス) or the IchiNichi JoshaKen (一日 乗車券).
ref: http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/arrange/travel/practical/tonai_ticket.html

Answer (score 0):

A day after typhoon, with no bus and no train available at that day, we took taxi between Myiazu and Fukuchyama (somewhat about 50 km I think). The driver discussed something over his phone and, I think, re-planed the route around some closed road.

If was most saving budget travel ever for me as it saved the airline tickets were were about to lose, being unable to come to the airport at time. The price was about 18 000 yen, nothing insane for three people.